"wsl --update" is apparently not a thing on my machine
I'm trying to get Docker Desktop to run (among other things) and I keep failing at WSL, or rather WSL2. Everywhere (the setup, online, whatever) tells me to just run wsl.exe --update or wsl --update.
But both in CMD and Powershell (both admin and not), --update seems to simply NOT be an existing parameter. It's not listed in the options I get with --help and that help page is all I get when I run that command.
I feel like I'm going crazy with this.
I'm on Windows 11 Pro, rather fresh install.

Prior to trying to install Docker you ran wsl --install?

I'm not absolutely certain what did it but I enabled Hyper-V on my machine [both in Windows and in BIOS generally enabled any and everything to do with Virtualization] and then restarted the PC (which I had - I think - done before and in between any step) and that fixed it.
How the wsl.exe managed to work but refuse (without an error) to update is still beyond me but if you're as confused as me maybe try it.
Edit: Thanks to u/Ramhound for pointing it out, I very likely ran wsl --install somewhere in between getting desperate and it working (before I enabled Hyper-V, that fixed the issue that arose after wsl was (somewhat) working)

Sounds like you never ran the command to install WSL, Hyper-V isn’t required for WSL, so installing Hyper-V wouldn’t have resolved your problem. Something else you did prior to enabling Hyper-V was likely the real solution

@Ramhound that was it. I don't know why I expected consistency and sanity from a Microsoft product but my main issue was that there wasn't even an error or anything of the likes. Just the wsl exe existing (aka seemingly being installed and available) and still refusing otherwise common commands. The hyper-V thing was for another error that occured AFTER wsl got past the --update bit. I'll expand what I actually did, thanks

You can’t expect WSL to work if you don’t follow the instructions to install it

@Ramhound you can expect a sane application to tell you that though. And if an .exe is preinstalled, you can expect it to be installed. Not weirdly halfway
